# Why does add SUCCESS action in ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have noticed in ngrx tutorials that when writing actions they declare for example:

```
GET_MATIERES = '[matiereList] Get Matieres',
SUCCESS_GET_MATIERES = '[matiereList] Success Get Matieres',
```

Why don't use only

```
GET_MATIERES = '[matiereList] Get Matieres',
```

When Should we use `SUCCESS` action and when it's useless to do it ?

Comment: a GET is an action that will usually trigger some kind of http request effect so that it can be mapped to a SUCCESS or FAIL type action... how would you accurately handle a failure without these concepts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `effects` you need to have `success` action and also having `fail` action as optional.

so the flow will be like that

```
1 - dispatch action

2 - effect catch the action

2.1 - effect calls http service

2.2 - effect dispatch success action with data received from http 

3 - reducer catch the success action and updates store
```

If you don't want to use `effects` flow will be like below

```
1 - call an angular service

1.1 - angular service calls http

1.2 - angular service dispatch action with data receives from http

2 - reducer catch the action and updates store
```

Although using effects will cause more boiler plate code, but also it has the advantage of chaining the actions, for example after login you want to retrieve client info, or after save an invoice, you want to refresh list of invoices

Comment: Thanks , it clear now. so if I would call data in store without making again an api call , should I only dispatch Success action ?

Comment: not really, if you are using effects your http service call will be done in effect and also you can chain actions. if you don't use effects, you will create angular service to do http calls and dispatch actions with result of http call